# GitHub Laravel App Sync

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, laravel-5

I just created a Laravel App (I'm completely new to Laravel and also don't have so much experience with Git(Hub)).

I created it locally on my computer with the `composer require "laravel/installer"`command and then ran `composer create-project`. I also added authentification with new table rows (migration) etc, downloaded some things and e.g. donwloaded another language pack.

Now I uploaded everything to GitHub, except the things that are in .gitignore (that looks like the following):

```
# Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
### Laravel template
vendor/
node_modules/

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
bootstrap/cache/
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
### Composer template
composer.phar
/vendor/

# Commit your application's lock file http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file
# You may choose to ignore a library lock file http://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file
# composer.lock
.gitignore
.idea/
```

Basically what I tried on another computer now, was running composer install and then a php artisan migrate (to get the databases). But this didn't work. There where quite some errors, what I at least noticed was that I still got a `.env.example` instead of a `.env`. So there was a `env.example` uploaded instead of a `.env`, is this correct?

However, whats the best practice or a good way to achieve what I want? Normally I'm working on the project on the computer I created the app, but sometimes I also want to work on and test something on another computer, so I need a local instace. After pushing everything to Github, what do I have to do on another copmuter to get my app running?

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.3

Comment: .env contains all your private information: Database logins etc. So within your .gitignore, tracking of your .env file will be ignored. => You don't want to upload your passwords to git.
Simply create another .env file on your other computer.

Comment: @TimL and how do I do this? Okay, entering the database login etc. is for sure, but I need an applícation key. How do I get this one? And are the other things I did correctly? So using composer install and then running artisan migrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TimL said in the comments this will be because you're `.env` file won't have been set up. You're `.env-example` is there for you to copy to make life easier.

You can either copy and paste it over, or if you using the command line:

```
cp .env-example .env
```

Then you populate it with the details for that environment.

Finally, to generate your application key just run the command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

and this will generate the key for you.

The only other manual thing I can think of it creating the database before you use migrate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yep, this worked, thank you. So its quite easy in the end.